Function successfully called from other .py file, but failing to run (Python 3.x, tkinter)
I have made a short program that extracts sample accounts data and drops it into a template, controlled by a button that selects which accounting rules to follow.
Initially, I created two functions(ifrs_selected and us_gaap_selected), and the code worked as expected, i.e. printing either "IFRS" or "US GAAP" to the console and then selecting the relevant template for printing based on the result.
Original code below:

###ENTER ACCOUNTING STANDARDS---------------------------------
acc_principles = 0          #set the acc_principles variable to 0

def ifrs_selected():        #create the function to run if IFRS is selected   
    global acc_principles
    acc_principles = "IFRS"


def us_gaap_selected():     #create the function to run if US GAAP is selected
    global acc_principles
    acc_principles = "US GAAP"


#Create the buttons
button = tk.Button(standards_enter, width=15, height=4, text="IFRS", command=ifrs_selected) #<--- create IFRS button 
button.pack()
button = tk.Button(standards_enter, width=15, height=4, text="US GAAP", command=us_gaap_selected) #<--- create US GAAP button 
button.pack()

standards_enter.mainloop()  #<--- set the button selection to run on closing the popup

print(acc_principles)        #<--- print chosen accounting standards to console

if acc_principles == "IFRS": #<--------- select Word template to use based on accounting standards selected
    template = ifrs_template
else:
    template = us_gaap_template
#-------------------------------------------------------------------

I have been experimenting with calling functions from other files and so decided to move ifrs_selected and us_gaap_selected to another file (accounts_functions.py, in the same folder), and then tried calling them. It appears that they are being pulled into the program correctly, I'm receiving no errors on that point, but when I click the button, I now only get 0 printed to the console, indicating that the function is not running when I click the button. I've been trying to figure out where I'm going wrong here, but I'm at a bit of a loss. Is anyone able to explain where my mistake is, please?
Code used to pull from other file below:
###ENTER ACCOUNTING STANDARDS---------------------------------
import accounts_functions as af

acc_principles = 0          #set the acc_principles variable to 0

#Create the buttons
button = tk.Button(standards_enter, width=15, height=4, text="IFRS", command=af.ifrs_selected) #<--- create IFRS button 
button.pack()
button = tk.Button(standards_enter, width=15, height=4, text="US GAAP", command=af.us_gaap_selected) #<--- create US GAAP button 
button.pack()

standards_enter.mainloop()  #<--- set the button selection to run on closing the popup

print(acc_principles)        #<--- print chosen accounting standards to console

if acc_principles == "IFRS": #<--------- select Word template to use based on accounting standards selected
    template = ifrs_template
else:
    template = us_gaap_template
#-------------------------------------------------------------------

Initial results: either "IFRS" or "US GAAP"
Results once I change to pull from other file: 0
Expected results: either "IFRS" or "US GAAP"

I'm very sorry - the code looked cleaner when I prepared the question, but the formatting has got messed up when showing here.

Thank you for editing the question, Grismar - massively more readable and greatly appreciated!

The problem is your use of globals. Although common, it's generally not a great practice and your problem nicely illustrates why.
Consider this program:
x = 1


def x_to_2():
    global x
    x = 2


x_to_2()

print(x)

Output:
2

Now, refactoring like you did into a main.py:
import functions

x = 1

functions.x_to_2()

print(x)

And a functions.py:
def x_to_2():
    global x

    x = 2

Running main.py now gives you:
1

Since the x in main.py and the one in the functions.py no longer refer to the same variable, the outcome changes. You may have expected global variables to be global across all your modules, but that's not the case.
Consider what would happen if two people wrote a module, both defined a global x and then a third wants to use those modules. They would break simply because of a conflict of globals. So, globals are scoped to the module.
If you insist on using globals, put them in one place and import them wherever you need them, like you would a function - this avoids the circular references you'd end up with otherwise, if you tried to import your globals from multiple places everywhere.
Passing values as arguments to function parameters is generally a better way to go about things. Another way to solve it would be to make your functions methods of a class and keep the value in the class, and access it on that.
Edit: you asked for an example of solving the problem with function parameters and using a class.
With function parameters, main.py:
import functions

x = 1

x = functions.x_to_2(x)

print(x)

And functions.py:
def x_to_2(x):
    # we're passing x, but not using it, the example is too trivial
    # but you could use the value passed in as well, e.g. return x + 2
    return 2

A bit more useful, with a class main.py:
import functions as f

f.MyClass.x = 1

f.MyClass.x_to_2()

print(f.MyClass.x)

And functions.py:
class MyClass:
    # this class attribute is the same wherever the class is accessible
    x = 0

    # a 'classmethod' can operate on class attributes, like x
    @classmethod
    def x_to_2(cls):
        cls.x = 2

You'll find that both these examples print 2 as expected.
Note that this use of a class is atypical. Classes are often used to define a type which can be used to instantiate many objects. A final example of that in this trivial context, main.py:
import functions as f

# defining two objects, to show that only it changes, if we only call the method on that
my_obj0 = f.MyClass(0)
my_obj1 = f.MyClass(1)

print(my_obj0.x, my_obj1.x)

my_obj0.x_to_2()

print(my_obj0.x, my_obj1.x)

And functions.py:
class MyClass:
    # this class can be instantiated many times, and those instances can be
    # passed around, like any other value (all types are objects in Python, in fact)

    def __init__(self, initial_x):
        # this is just a regular attribute, not a class attribute
        self.x = initial_x

    # where a class method gets passed the class automatically,
    # a normal method gets passed the instance (self) automatically
    def x_to_2(self):
        self.x = 2

Output:
0 1
2 1

In your specific example, using a class with some class attributes could be the right way to go, and passing the class method will work like you expect (instead of passing the normal function).

Global variables aren't inherently bad, you just have to know that they are scoped to a module. It's like local variables are scoped to a function call. The alternatives are functional programming (much harder) or OOP (might be confusing to beginners)

Global variables are often a source of confusion for new programmers, because they rarely behave as they expect (OP is a good example) and passing arguments to functions is not even close to "functional programming". Global variables have their place and appropriate uses, but using them as a golden hammer for everything new programmers pass around just creates problems and bad habits. Note that I am not saying  "inherently bad" but "generally not a great practice" and I think that's 100% accurate.

Thank you for this answer. I had used the global variables as I had understood that was how to take a variable and use it outside of the confines of that particular function - I was unaware of the broader issues it would cause. I've been working on trying to address your final paragraph, about passing values as arguments or making the functions into methods of a class, but I don't seem to be getting very far. Could I ask for an example to illustrate the point, please? I'm not asking for an answer, as I'd like to learn and figure it out, but I'm stabbing around in the dark at the moment!

I've added some examples showing solutions with function parameters and return values (which doesn't really suit the example, but I think you can see what happens), with a class and class attributes, and finally with object instances from the class - but the class attribute solution may be the best solution for your case, since it stays closest to how globals work, without most of the downsides. Alternately, you can import the global in your main script of course, but it's well worth becoming familiar with these concepts, as they allow for far more flexible and clean programming.
